# sometimes slow rendering, html + CSS

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am a trainee programmer and maybe I am asking something basic, but I feel really curious about it.
I am working on an app that renders a table. I am using DOM element in html. So, I create a table using document.createElement and append it to body of the file with document.body.appendChild. This is part of the code:

```
function render_tabla_DOM(tabla){
    var table;
    execute_in_steps([
        {
            what:"create objects",
            how:function(){
                table=document.createElement('table');
                for(var iFila=0; iFila<tabla.length; iFila++){
                    var fila=tabla[iFila];
                    var tr=table.insertRow(-1);
                    for(var iCol=0; iCol<fila.length; iCol++){
                        var celda=fila[iCol];
                        var td=tr.insertCell(-1);
                        td.textContent=celda;
                        td.contentEditable=true;
                    }
                }
                table.className='my_tabla';
            },
        },{
            what:"add to the website",
            how:function(){
                document.body.appendChild(table);
            }
        }
    ]);
}
```

I have the function execute_in_steps() because I am what to control the time it takes to do each of the things (since I want to do the app as fast as possible). To create the object table with the quantity of rows and columns I need, it takes about a second.

The data for the table is an external .js file containing an array in sql format (since in the future I will use that database) and then I have a .CSS file to make the table look nice and I tried to set everything myself, because the auto options makes the table render too slow:

```
.my_tabla{
    table-layout: fixed; 
    width:50cm; 
    margin:0px;
}

.my_tabla td{
    border:1px solid grey;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100px;
    height:0.5cm;
    margin:0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

The curios thing is that when I go to the browser and see the table, let´s say that 70% of the time, the table takes 6 or 7 seconds to show and the 30% times remaining, it takes 1 second and a half. I have a windows 7 system and the browser is Chrome, eventually it will be Safari.
Does anybody know the reason for that difference of time?

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question (Add relevant code, check the console in your developer tools, show errors, etc).

Comment: And make sure you append all the created elements at once, not one after another. E. g. create A, create B, create C, append C to B, append B to A, append A to DOM.

Comment: Look up browser caching.

Comment: Is it clearer now that I added some code? I don´t know if I specify the question properly!